# Удаление объекта после его создания при нажатии клавиши

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создаю два объекта при нажатии лкм. При нажатии на правую клавишу мыши мне нужно, чтобы они удалились. Не могу это сделать из за модификаторов доступов у созданных объектов.
  Вот код:

```
public Vector3 spawn1;
    public Vector3 spawn2;
    public GameObject spawn1_1;
    public GameObject spawn2_2;
    public GameObject box;
    public bool flag = false;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        spawn1 = spawn1_1.transform.position;
        spawn2 = spawn2_2.transform.position;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !flag)
        {  
            flag = true;
            GameObject cube1 = Instantiate (box, spawn1, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            GameObject cube2 = Instantiate (box, spawn2, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            cube1.transform.rotation = new Quaternion (Random.Range (1, 360), Random.Range (1, 360), Random.Range (1, 360),0);
            cube2.transform.rotation = new Quaternion (Random.Range (1, 360), Random.Range (1, 360), Random.Range (1, 360),0);
            cube1.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (Vector3.forward*Random.Range(1000,5000));
            cube2.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (Vector3.forward*Random.Range(1000,5000));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вставил скриншот в проект - не компилируется. Предоставьте что нибудь, что компилируется и воспроизводит вашу проблему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Не могу это сделать из за модификаторов доступов у созданных объектов

Не из-за модификаторов доступа, а из-за того, что вы объявляете их в одном конкретном методе, область которых ограничена тем самым методом.

Самое первое решение "в лоб" - вынести объявление в начало к остальным полям:

```
...
public GameObject box;
public bool flag = false;
GameObject cube1;
GameObject cube2;


void Start () {
    spawn1 = spawn1_1.transform.position;
    spawn2 = spawn2_2.transform.position;
}

void Update () {
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !flag)  {  
        flag = true;
        cube1 = Instantiate (box, spawn1, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        cube2 = Instantiate (box, spawn2, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        ...
```

---

А вообще, если объектов будет не два, а более, то их, как правило, заносят либо в список (List), либо словарь (Dictionary) и добавление/удаление производят именно в него/из него